# How to create a pop up animation with a modal using css?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, css-transitions, bootstrap-modal

I have already created the modal in css, but when I try changing the transition so that it pops more like a modal instead of fading in, it doesn't work. I've tried changing the duration and the transition type but it doesn't seem to apply. Am I using the wrong transition?

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mtbh24uL/

```
.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
```

My goal: to have more of a pop up effect like a real javascript modal. I basically need to create a modal like you see in the following picture. I'm not sure what the best approach is or the best plugin.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but what is your goal?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani my goal is for the animation of the modal to be more like a real javascript modal. Have a more pop up effect.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani any tips or advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could define a CSS animation for that and call this animation when you are clicking on the button. You can achieve this with adding the following CSS code. This is only an example to give you a rough idea of how your effect could look like. From this point you can even optimize and finetune the animation.

**CSS**

```
.overlay:target .popup{
  animation: popup 0.7s;
}

@keyframes popup {
  0%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50%{
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  60%{
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  70%{
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  80%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  90%{
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100%{
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}
.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* transition: all 0.3s ease-out; */
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}
.popup:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
}
.overlay:target .popup {
  animation: popup 0.7s;
}
.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .box {
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@keyframes popup {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
  <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Here i am</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div class="content">
      Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that's amazing. I'm not familiar with keyframes, seems really powerful. How about the arrow pointed in the image I posted? Any idea on how to create that? @SvenL

Comment: Yeah indeed you can do really great animations with keyframes. You could add such an arrow with a pseudo-element :after or :before on your div which pops up, in your case .popup. Will update the snippet. There is also this [website](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) where you can easily generate your own arrows.

Comment: nice! How about a curved arrow like in the img I posted? That's a nifty website though.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to getting the curved arrow, you can use the :after or :before pseudo element.  Something like this will achieve the desired effect:

**CSS**

```
.popup:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 0 solid transparent;
  border-left: 24px solid white;
  border-radius: 33px 0;
  top: -18px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 34px;
}
```